# getting message School:0x00559eba30b8b8 instead of displaying school name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'am trying to display school name which is related to members, but I got the School:0x00559eba30b8b8, instead the name.

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
 <%= member.name %>
 <%= member.email %>
 <%= member.school %>
<% end %>
```

result : John john@john.com #School:0x00559eba30b8b8

update:

with school_id I get the id of the school, but still don't know how to get the name.

How can I get the name of the school? 
Many thanks

Comment: Show us your controller and School + Member model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `school_id` in members table you need to print `school.name` instead of `school`

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
 <%= member.name %>
 <%= member.email %>
 <%= member.school.try(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

**NOTE:** `member.school` will return you an instance of `School` and you want to print just name.

Comment: Thank Deepak, this is the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Since `school` is not mandatory attribute, it can’t be just queried for the `name`, one should use `try` there:

```
<%= member.school.try :name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%= member.school.try(:name) %>
```

Note:- Assuming your `school` has attribute 'name'

Also in your controller where you finding `@members` use 'includes', something like

```
@members = member.where().includes(:school)
```

Comment: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass